# Wordpress paginate_links() function, 404s and trouble

Tags: wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404

This has been a horrendous, crippling, time stealing (two week) horrible horrible problem.

It might be rewriting, my use of custom posts, but after stripping out so much (and reducing some functionality of my theme) I've reduced my problem to this:

`paginate_links()` is putting out a link like this:

```
?s=cute&post_type=image&paged=2
```

When I changed the variable in the browser bar to page=2 (dropping the 'd').

```
?s=cute&post_type=image&page=2
```

It works correctly.

So my question reduced to this: **If I must get that function to output the "page" variable properly, how is that done?**

`paged` and `paged` are both used by WordPress. So conversely, how do I get `paged` recognized if that is better practice?

For all I know, this is indicative of some deeper issue I have in my theme, but for the life of me I can't see how else I could be going wrong!

EDIT:

Here is my code I'm using:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') )

        $paged = get_query_var('paged');

    elseif ( get_query_var('page') )

        $paged = get_query_var('page');

    else
        $paged = 1;     

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $stuff_to_echo =  paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'array'
    ) );
```

EDIT 2 - If above is good, here is another possible area the problem might be happening. I'll post the creation of the custom post type and the rewrite rules -

```
//image custom post type

add_action( 'init', 'symbiostock_image_manager_register' );

function symbiostock_image_manager_register( )
{
    //creating custom post type for image

    $labels = array(
         'name' => 'Symbiostock Images',
        'singular_name' => 'Image',
        'add_new' => 'New Image',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Image',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Image',
        'new_item' => 'New Image',
        'all_items' => 'All Images',
        'view_item' => 'View Image',
        'search_items' => 'Search Images',
        'not_found' => 'No image found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No images found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'RF Images' 
    );

    $args = array(

         'labels' => $labels,
        'singular_label' => __( 'Image' ),
        'description' => 'Image Listings',
        'menu_position' => 100,
        'menu_icon' => symbiostock_IMGDIR . '/symbiostock_icon2.png',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'supports' => array(
             'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail' 
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
             'slug' => 'image',
            'with_front' => false 
        ) 

    );


    register_post_type( 'image', $args );

    register_taxonomy( 'image-type', array(
         'image' 
    ), array(
         'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Image Categories',
        'singular_label' => 'Image Type',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' =>false,
        'public' => true, 
        'slug' => 'image-type' 
    ) );

    register_taxonomy( 'image-tags', array(
         'image' 
    ), array(
         'hierarchical' => false,
         'rewrite' => true,
         'query_var' => true,
        'singular_label' => 'Image Keyword',

        'hierarchical'            => false,
        'labels'                  => $labels,
        'show_ui'                 => true,
        'show_admin_column'       => true,
        'update_count_callback'   => '_update_post_term_count',


        'slug' => 'image-tag',               
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Image Keywords', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Keywords', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Images' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Image Keywords' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Image Keyword' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Image Keyword' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Image Keyword' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Keyword Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Image Keywords' ),
            ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'search-images', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false, 
            'hierarchical' => false 
        ),
    ) );

}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'symbiostock_image_directory' );

function symbiostock_image_directory( )
{
    add_meta_box( 'symbiostock-image-meta', 'Symbiostock Image Info', 'symbiostock_image_manager_meta_options', 'image', 'normal', 'high' );

}
```

And here are the rewrite rules further down -

```
add_action( 'init', 'symbiostock_rewrite' );

function symbiostock_rewrite( )
{   

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('typename','typename/%year%%postname%/' , true , 1);
    add_rewrite_rule('typename/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$','index.php?typename=$matches[2]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I've had the same problem and solved it by changing the permalink of the page that was causing the 404.

This is because, apparently, you cannot have a page-slug with the same name as your custom post type.

All credit goes to Ryan S. for sharing the original solution: http://www.sutanaryan.com/2013/09/404-error-in-custom-post-type-pagination-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Under your args for paginate_links() I would ensure that you have your format set properly.  'paged' is typically used for obtaining the "current page" the user is on (Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query)

```
'format' => '?page=%#%'
```

it sounds like you have it set to '?paged=%#%'

Here is a complete example

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'format'    => '?page=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages
);
paginate_links($args);
```

Comment: I updated the original post. Somehow something is getting hijacked to give me a 404. And thank you very much for the response. wordpress.org seems to ignore most help requests on this subject.

Comment: So I'm still pretty much in the dark here. I can't see anything wrong with my query/paginate_links. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to show your site as well.  Currently the only thing I do not see in your code is the global $wp_query; but that shouldn't affect the formatting issue you are having.  Can you show the larger picture of the code as well?  I cannot think of too much that would affect it but there may be something else that may be causing an issue.

Comment: Thank you for checking into this. Instead of posting everything which is a lot of code, I figured the next possible area of problem was rewrite rules where I've set up the custom post type. If you can verify there is not a problem here, then I might just be on my own! I've just posted the next set of code in the opening post.

Comment: This is interesting - for my custom taxonomy page PAGINATION WORKS! Is it possible that I somehow destroyed custom post type pagination everywhere BUT the taxonomy page?

Comment: Following the trail, I found this: **?image-tags=searchword** paginates fine, whereas **?s=searchword** breaks! I don't know why this is, but I'm considering modifying the query at init unless there is a better solution.

Comment: something with the ?typename is bothering me but cant really figure out what it is.  Regardless I think you may be interested in this article about rewrite for custom post types http://vocecommunications.com/blog/2010/11/adding-rewrite-rules-for-custom-post-types/

Comment: Thanks guys I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but is appropriate in this case.

I simply set up a redirect to the taxonomy page in the event someone is searching this post type.

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'image_search_redirect' );

function image_search_redirect( $query ) {
    if ( ( is_search() && get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'image' ) ) {

        wp_redirect(home_url("?image-tags=") . urlencode(get_query_var('s')));

        exit(); 
    }
}
```

This is not as much a solution as a creative work-around. There should be no reason why I get a 404 not found on the "paged=" variable. If some future person knows a better solution I'd love to know one!